# Can't delete an object that has a folder path, in google cloud storage using .net API

Tags: .net, google-cloud-storage

My code is:

```
 ObjectsResource.DeleteRequest dr;
 dr = new ObjectsResource.DeleteRequest(service, "bucketName", "aa/bb.jpg");
 dr.Execute();
```

If i have an image on the root bucket (say "bb.jpg") i can delete it without a problem,
 But if the object has a path in its name like my example I get an exception.
 The response is not JSON but a string "not found" with the 404.
 If I URL Encode the name, I get a JSON error of not found with the 404.

I can't find a way to delete an object with path in its name.

Comment: I wonder, what does `dr.HttpMethod()` return?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

I had to add this to my web.config:

```
 <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>
```

It was quite a headache!

Here are links to a discussion about this problem(bug for my view)

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=454

http://blog.techedup.net/gce-dotnet4/